# What does "grep -v "^.$"" do

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a script for cleaning up of data files

The command:

```
for i in `find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -mtime +15 -print|grep -v "^.$" |grep data-`
```

I tried running the command without the `grep -v` function and I don't see any difference.

I would like to know what the `grep -v "^.$"` does. I did not create this script and I cannot find anything online.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -v "^.$"` will print all lines from input except those that have only a single character.

As it is used in:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -mtime +15 -print|grep -v "^.$"
```

we can assume that it is to discard the current working directory (`.`) from `find`'s output (shown when relative path `.` is used) , which can easily be achieved by `-mindepth 1` option, although here it is redundant as you are using absolute path in `find`.

Later you are only searching for files with `data-` in their names by `grep data-`, this is redundant too. You can put all logic in a single `find` invocation:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -name '*data-*' -mtime +15 -print
```

Drop `-print` too, it is the default action:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -name '*data-*' -mtime +15
```

Just to note, if you are looking for only files, add `-type f` too:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -type f -name '*data-*' -mtime +15
```

Comment: And since anything found by `find /ddomain/data/shop12/` will have the `/ddomain/data/shop12/` prefix, there will be no such thing as a name formed of a single character.  So the answer to the OP's question is: it does nothing at all. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yes, in this specific case. But the explicit question was: ”I would like to know what the `grep -v "^.$"` does”

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, `grep -v '^.$'` filters out lines that consist of exactly one character (lines that consist of the beginning of the line (`^`) followed by one character (`.`) followed by the end of the line (`$`). Another way to write it would be `grep -vx .` where the `-x` makes the `^` and `$` implicit (the `.` matches on the whole line).

On the output of:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -mtime +15 -print
```

That makes little sense because the output of that `find` command will typically consist of lines like:

```
/ddomain/data/shop12/foo
/ddomain/data/shop12/foo/bar
...
```

The only way for that output to contain lines with a single character is if there's a file whose name is something like `foo<newline>X<newline>`. That's perfectly possible, but I'd say it's unlikely it was the intent of that command.

Possibly, that command was (incorrectly) adapted from:

```
find . -mtime +15 -print | grep -v '^.$' | grep data-
```

Where that `grep` was intended to filter out the `.` entry (even then, `grep -Fvx .` would have been more appropriate). However, then it would have made more sense to write it:

```
find . ! -name . -path '*data-*' -mtime +15
```

If you want to filter-out the top-level directory with `find /ddomain/data/shop12/`, you'd do it as:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/. ! -name . -path '*data-*' -mtime +15
```

Or if your `find` implementation supports the `-mindepth` predicate:

```
find /ddomain/data/shop12/ -mindepth 1 -path '*data-*' -mtime +15
```

Answer (score 1):

It removes the `.` directory from the list of `find` results. It's easier to explain by an example:

```
find . -print
.
./prova2
./prova2/prova2  

find . -print | grep -v '^.$'
./prova2
./prova2/prova2
```

As you can see, in the first snippet of code, we find the `.` result. So, you pass it to the actions taken by the `for` cycle.
In the second snippet, you decide to skip the `.` directory from the results of `find`, so you don't send it to the `for` cycle.

Comment: Not only dot, but any one symbol result

Comment: You're right. I've answered basing my explanation on the context of the script. I really think the meaning of that is cutting out the `.` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The command grep -v "^.$" will "remove" from the stream the current directory and any file/directory which have name from one symbol. For example let execute

```
ls -a
.  ..  a1 a2 a3
```

and let exec it with the grep

```
ls -a |grep -v "^.$"
..
a1
a2
a3
```

As you can see the dot disappear

Answer (score -1):

`grep -v '^.$'` excludes lines with only one character.

Example:

```
echo "foo
> bar
> x" | grep -v '^.$'
foo
bar
```